# Convert list of items to list of tree nodes that have children

Tags: c#, tree

I have the following class

```
 public class Item 
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }           
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And the following class for tree view

```
public class TreeViewModel
{
    public TreeViewModel()
    {
        this.Children = new List<TreeViewModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Expanded { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return Children.Any(); }
    }

    public IList<TreeViewModel> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

I will receive list of items and I would to convert it to tree.

the item that not have parent id it will the main node.

example: if i have the following items

```
item[0] = Id:0 Text:User ParentId:3

item[1] = Id:1 Text:Role ParentId:3

item[2] = Id:2 Text:SubUser ParentId:0

item[3] = Id:3 Text:Admin ParentId:null

item[4] = Id:4 Text:SuperAdmin ParentId:null

item[5] = Id:5 Text:Doha ParentId:4
```

the following item it will list of tree

[image]

I tried to make recursive function to do that , but i have no result

Comment: Please show your recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fast **O(N)** time complexity method of doing that:

```
List<Item> list = ...;
// Pre create all nodes and build map by Id for fast lookup
var nodeById = list
    .Select(item => new TreeViewModel { Id = item.Id, Text = item.Text })
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Id);
// Build hierarchy
var tree = new List<TreeViewModel>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    var nodeList = item.ParentId == null ? tree, nodeById[item.ParentId.Value].Children;
    nodeList.Add(nodeById[item.Id]);
}
```

Comment: thank you  , it is works with me:) ,, but now  after i generate the tree i want to delete some nodes , for example nodes that have id =0 and has no children ,, i try lot and get nothing ,, tree.RemoveAll(x.id==0 && x.hasChildern==false) ,,, how I can delete from tree from all childrens ??????

Comment: @Doha You are welcome. What about the delete issue, please post a new question and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Doha Looks like the community doesn't like the new question. By my understanding, you want to delete some nodes from the result. Since the `tree` list contains the **root** nodes, end every node contains `Children` list, you can make a recursive method that does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a recursive function to do this:

```
var models = items.Select(i => new TreeViewModel
{
    Id = i.Id,
    ...
}).ToList();

foreach (var model in models){
    model.Children.AddRange(models.Where(m => m.ParentId == model.Id));
}
```

If you then want to get the roots of your tree, you can use:

```
var roots = models.Where(m => !m.ParentId.HasValue);
```

Comment: @Mr.White Those items that are related will be a part of the same tree.

Comment: Totally missed the second part where you check for the ParentId  :/

Comment: This is an O(n^2) algorithm that could trivially be done as an O(n) algorithm, and as such will scale very poorly as the number of nodes increases.

Comment: @Mr.White That's not true.